# Obtener el último registro de cada producto PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos días amigos informáticos, tengo un problema y estaría muy agradecido que me echaran una mano. El planteamiento es el siguiente: Yo tengo una tabla llamada salida, y en la tabla salida se insertan varios registros, entre ellos el id del producto  `id_service_id_salida` y la fecha de salida `fecha_salida`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera poder obtener el último registro de cada producto

este es parte del codigo:

```
<tbody>
     <?php

$consulta= "SELECT * FROM salida 
            INNER JOIN service ON salida.id_service_id_salida=service.id_service
            INNER JOIN user ON salida.id_user_id_salida =user.id_user 
            WHERE salida.id_service_id_salida IN (SELECT MAX(salida.id_service_id_salida))
            GROUP BY salida.id_service_id_salida ASC"; 
 $bd->consulta($consulta)
 while ($fila=$bd->mostrar_registros()) { ?>
 <tr>    

 <?php $id= $fila->id_salida; ?>
 <td  width="5%"><?php echo $fila->id_service_id_salida; ?></td>
 <td  width="25%"> <?php echo $fila->name_service; ?></td>
 <td  width="25%"><?php echo $fila->name_user; ?></td>
 <td  width="20%"><?php echo $fila->fecha_salida; ?>  </td>
 <td width="25%" class="hidden-print noprin">
 </tr>
<?php 
 }
?>
</tbody>
```

Actualmente muestra el primer registro de cada producto y necesito que muestre el ultimo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y añadir en modo texto el código de lo que lleves intentado? Eso servirá de punto de partida para que te puedan dar respuestas más fácilmente.

Comment: Te refieres al último registro ingresado o al último registro según la fecha.

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código como texto y no como imagen. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer una `sub-consulta` en el `where` para validar que la `salida` es exactamente la última.

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
    SELECT * 
    FROM salida AS A
        INNER JOIN service AS B
            ON B.id_service = A.id_service_id_salida
        INNER JOIN user AS C
            ON C.id_user = A.id_user_id_salida
    WHERE A.id_salida = (
        SELECT T.id_salida 
        FROM salidas AS T
        WHERE T.id_service_id_salida = A.id_service_id_salida
        ORDER BY T.fecha_salida DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!! esto me funciono perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que la columna de los id's de producto es id_service_id_salida, podríar probar con esto;

```
select id_service_id_salida, max(fecha_salida)
from tu_tabla
group by id_service_id_salida
```